# Generate Model relationship in laravel 5.4

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.4, relationships

I have 3 table & model:

```
1) product
-----------
id, name, c_id, sku

2) category
----------
id, name, parent_c_id

3) parent_category
-----------------
id, name
```

How to get product detail with category and parent category using eloquent relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eloquent let's you define relationships with between your models/tables inside your model classes. To define that a model has a foreign key, you can use `belongsTo` to define that your model  belongs to another model.

```
// Product.php
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}

// Category.php
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ParentCategory');
}
```

Eloquent will look for a column named `<lowercase modelname>_id` in the database table. For `Product` that would mean `category_id`, as `Product` *belongs to* `Category`.

If you don't want to change your column names, you can define the foreign key as the second argument:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'c_id');
```

You can read up on these relationships in the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

---

**Update #1**

It looks like I misunderstood your question a little, so based on your comment, I think this should work:

```
Product::with('category')
    ->with('category.parent_category')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Product::with('category')->get();
this will return only product and category value, but i want product with category and parent category data.